# Using scanf until EOF to insert values into nodes

Tags: c, linked-list, scanf, nodes, eof

I want to get user inputs from scanf and then save those integers into nodes (and link the nodes onto a linked list). The user can input integers until they hit ctrl+d.

This is what I currently have, but once the user hits ctrl+d, my program infinitely prints "enter int values:". I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly, because once x == EOF, it should break out of the loop.

Where would I go from this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insertNode(struct Node **startRef, int data);
void insertNode(struct Node **startRef, int data){
    struct Node *ptr1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr1->data = data;
    ptr1->next = *startRef;
    *startRef = ptr1;
}

int main(){
    int vals;
    struct node *start = NULL;

    for(;;){
        int x = &vals;
        if(x==EOF){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("enter int values: ");
            scanf("%d", vals);
            insertNode(&start,vals);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use `&` address-of: `scanf("%d", &vals);` but the compiler won't like `int x = &vals;` Also why would the input value be `EOF`? It seems a bit of a muddle. There are plenty of examples of reading `int` values to be found.

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings:`int vals; ... scanf("%d", vals);` should warn.

Comment: And you need to check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure it actually read some input - or you'll infinite loop when it gets stuck.

Comment: Use: `while (scanf("%d", &vals) == 1) insertNode(&start, vals);`.  If you want the prompt too, use `while (printf("enter an integer: ") > 0 && scanf("%d", &vals) == 1)` in the loop condition — `printf()` reports on how many characters it wrote, so you can use that to test whether the `printf()` succeeded.  You could instead use a comma operator to separate the `printf()` from the `scanf()` and test.  Note that if `scanf()` returns 0, you've got problems — probably a non-numeric, non-white-space character in the input stream.